# How to match partial Input with regular expression in React js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native

```
Mongo DataBase Value : (01)00884465657210(17)210930
User Input for Search : Value : (01)00884465657210(17)21
```

I am tired using below code for match partial value and get detail but whole value match and partial value not match using my code

```
 let searchText = "(01)00884465657210(17)21";

 let query = await collection.find({
   'UserId': searchText == '' ? {$regex: searchText} :searchText
 })
```

If user enter partial number or whole number that time get related all details

Comment: Try adding ‘$options’: ‘i’ in your query. Like {'UserId': {'$regex': searchText, '$options': 'i'}}

Comment: I tried $options but in string regular expression "()" so it was not working.
Without regular expression it's working file but i need match with regular expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109150/mongo-regex-with-parenthesis-and-word-boundary check this to match parenthesis.

Comment: you have to add /b before it.